# Copy Data into smaller Buffer in Compute shader

Tags: c#, gpu, hlsl, compute-shader

Some Context:
I am using C# and HLSL.
I have a program which stores some 3d Data in a two buffers on the GPU. This contains positions (float3) and layer information (int).

So there are these points described by their position and for each point there's layer information as well stored within one int value (32 layers of which only 2 are actually used).

The first layer/first bit of the int value basically means if the point is rendered, while the second means if it is selected (the important part for my question).

I basically want to get all the points which are selected (layer two is set true) and save them somewhere else. This brings me to some questions:

Does it make sense to separate the points on the GPU and get the Data to CPU afterwards to convert byte values to float and save them?

So far I did the following: I calculated the amount of selected points with some compute shader calls. I use this information to create a new buffer where I want to store only the selected points. Here comes the next question. If I do that in my compute shader I would need to know the number of point every thread writes to this buffer, which I dont know, right? Or can I somehow just write to the next unoccupied field in the buffer every time a thread finds a selected point?

Or would you suggest a completely different approach?

I hope I could describe my problem in an understandable way.

Maybe this image helps to clarify: [Buffer visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M4jV.png)